# an approximation of the sum of roots of unity to the powers of 2

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

How to prove that $$(1+\omega^0)+(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n+(1+\omega^3)^n+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+(1+\omega^{r-1})^n$$ can be approximated as $2^n$, where $\omega^n=1$. For example, $$(1 + 1)^n + (1 + \omega)^n + (1 + \omega^2)^n) = 2^n + (-\omega^2)^n + (-\omega)^n)$$ $$(1 + 1)^n + (1 + \omega)^n= 2^n $$

Comment: $w^r=1$ or $w^n=1$.?

Comment: sorry, it's n $\omega^n$

Comment: @MyGlasses Do you have some thoughts?

Comment: Is your example true.? $n=3$.?

Comment: yes, and also $n=4$

Comment: also $n=2$, all of them

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172291/how-to-prove-an-approximation-of-a-combinatorics-identity

Answer (score 1):

We need:

$$\begin{align}S &= \sum_{i = 0}^{n}{n\choose i}\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} (w^j)^i\right)\\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n}{n\choose i}\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} (w^i)^j\right)\end{align}$$

Now the inner sum is just a geometric series, and we all know that for $x \not= 1$,

$$1 + x + ... + x^{n - 1} = \frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x}$$

So we have

$$\begin{align}S &= {n\choose 0}\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}(w^0)^j\right) + {n\choose n}\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}(w^n)^j\right) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{n\choose i}\left(\frac{1 - (w^i)^n}{1 - w^i}\right)\\
&= n + n + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{n\choose i}\left(\frac{1 - (w^n)^i}{1 - w^i}\right)\\
&= 2n + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{n\choose i}\left(\frac{1 - (w^n)^i}{1 - w^i}\right)\end{align}$$

Note that I've separated the case for $i = 0, n$ because $w^0, w^n = 1$ which will cause the geometric sum formula to fail.

Next, by definition $w^n = 1$ so we get

$$\begin{align}S &= 2n + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{n\choose i}\left(\frac{1 - (1)^i}{1 - w^i}\right)\\
&= 2n + \sum_{i = 1}^n {n\choose i}(0)\\
&= 2n\end{align}$$

[Wolfram verifies](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%20%2B%20w%5E0)%5E6%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20w%5E1)%5E6%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20w%5E2)%5E6%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20w%5E3)%5E6%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20w%5E4)%5E6%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20w%5E5)%5E6%20where%20w%20%3D%20e%5E%7B2i%20pi%20%2F%206%7D) for $n = 6$.

Comment: so it's just exactly $2^n$

Comment: My bad, made some mistakes in my calculations. It turns out to be $2n$. Wolfram verifies for the case $n = 4$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1+%2B+w%5E0)%5E4+%2B+(1+%2B+w%5E1)%5E4+%2B+(1+%2B+w%5E2)%5E4+%2B+(1+%2B+w%5E3)%5E4+where+w+%3D+e%5E%7B2i+pi+%2F+4%7D

Comment: Oh my god, but where is the mistake?

Comment: I confused terms of the inner sum with the outer sum, and forgot to consider the case when $i = n$ for which the geometric sum would fail as it will have a denominator of $1 - w^i = 1 - w^n = 0$. But it's fixed now :)

Comment: so the conclusion was $\sum_{k\ge 0}^{n-1}(1+w^k)^n$ =2n+2 right

Comment: $\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}(1 + w^i)^n = 2n$ if we want to be more precise with the upper limit.

Comment: there is something wrong with my problem, now I fixed it

Comment: it's$r$, not $n$

Comment: By changing the definition of $w$ you completely change the question. Perhaps you should start a new question with $w^r = 1$.

Comment: yes, I've started , it's here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172291/how-to-prove-an-approximation-of-a-combinatorics-identity