# How to prove an approximation of a combinatorics identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, approximation, roots-of-unity

How to prove that $$\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{rk} =\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}(1+w^j)^n$$ can be approximated as $\frac{2^n}{r}$, where $n\ge 0$, $r\ge 0$, $n>r$, $w^r=1$.

For example, $$(1 + 1)^n + (1 + \omega)^n + (1 + \omega^2)^n) = 2^n + (-\omega^2)^n + (-\omega)^n)$$ $$(1 + 1)^n + (1 + \omega)^n= 2^n $$

Comment: Do you really mean an infinite series on the LHS? Also, you forgot to say what $w$ is.

Comment: now it's done, LHS is an not infinite, depend on the number of $r$

Comment: Do you have some thoughts?

Comment: `LHS is an not infinite` Then write it for what it is. $\sum_{k \ge 0}$ doesn't have an implied upper bound. Maybe you meant $\sum_{k \ge 0, kr \le n}\,$.

Comment: How does this relate to your earlier question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171347/an-approximation-of-the-sum-of-roots-of-unity-to-the-powers-of-2 ? Is it just a duplicate? Why haven't you linked the two questions to each other?

Comment: not a duplicate

Comment: that one was $w^n=1$

Comment: now it's $w^r=1$

Comment: And why did you post this exact question to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263776/how-to-prove-an-approximation-of-a-combinatorics-identity without noting what you did on either site? This is abuse of the system.